# How do I represent " as a string in python without using '

Tags: python, string

As you know that python support both `'` and `"` for string like

```
a = 'str'
b = "str"
```

If I want to represent the symbol `"`, I can use:

```
a = '"'
```

However, I don't want to use `'`, is there any way? In java, which does not allow `'` for string representing, I can use:

```
a = "\""
```

but this escape won't work in python

```
print("\"") # >>> \"
```

Thanks

Comment: That is not what `print("\"")` prints.

Comment: *but this escape won't work in python*... Why do you think that?

Comment: @user2357112  it is not? it did print `\"` instead of `"` on mine

Comment: wait, it did, but I meant `r"\""`, can I do this with raw string?

Comment: raw string: `print(r""'"'"")` -> `"`

Comment: @StephenRauch: That's not really a raw string, though. It's implicitly concatenating `r""`, `'"'`, and `""`.

Comment: @StephenRauch wow,  that worked, but how.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use `'` and must use raw strings, then there is no way to express a single double quotation mark `"` as a string.

There are two methods of including a string delimiter (`'` or `"`) in a string:

1. Use the other delimiter for the string, e.g. `'"'` or `"'"`
2. Escape the character with a backslash, e.g. `"\""` or `'\''`

Your constraints remove both of those possibilities.

Comment: @Recessive huh? `r""" " """` is not `'"'`, yours has a space on either side.

Answer (score 1):

you can perhaps use a triple quoted string

```
print("""I wasn't, I shan't. "This is a quote".""")
```

your output should be

> > > I wasn't, I shan't. "This is a quote".